# my * is taking a higher specificity over my element tag and !important tag

Tags: css, header, css-specificity

[*" at 0.0 transparency][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5fil.png)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
[*" at 0.5 transparency][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfSNP.png)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
[*" at 1.0 transparency][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxOrn.png)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

The problem is that the "*" tag is taking a higher specificity over the "header" tag which should not be the case.

I placed the header element in a class, that didn't solve the problem.I also gave the header and id which also didn't work.I also gave the header element an "!important" tag but that also didnt workand as a last ditch effort I increased the z-index of the header to 1000 nad lowered the "z-index" of the "*" to 1 which also didn't help

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap");
 @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap");
 @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Encode+Sans:wght@500&display=swap");

* {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    background-color: rgba(36,37,42,1);
}

header{
    background-color: aquamarine;
    min-height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: sticky;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    z-index: 1000;
 }


 .navbar {
     font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
     font-weight: 500;
     font-size: 1em;
     width: 100%;
     height: 20%;
     padding-bottom: 0;
     position: sticky;
     top: 0;
}

.main-nav{
    float: right;
}

 .logo img {
     height: auto;
     width: 12%;
     padding: 0.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
      <a href="BOB.html" class="logo">
        <img src="#" alt="BOB Logo"/>
      </a>
      <div class="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav-links active">
            <a href="#" class="nav-links active">Home</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-links">
            <a href="#" class="nav-links">Stationary</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-links">
            <a href="#" class="nav-links">Furniture</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-links">
            <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
</header>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, welcome to SO! Don't post images of your code, but edit your question and post the code as a [reprex] instead (Hit the inverted [<>] button in the question toolbar).

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<link>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by adding a style which made the background of any element under Header transparent. `header * {background-color: transparent}`

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75264322/my-is-taking-a-higher-specificity-over-my-element-tag-and-important-tag/75264374?noredirect=1#comment132835050_75264374)

Answer (score -1):

1. A tag is more specific than an `*`.
2. `<header>` must be inside the `<body>` tag, not in `<head>`
3. There are other elements inside `<header>`, like `<navbar>` etc. And asterisk `*` affects them and fills them with `background-color: rgba(36,37,42,1);`
4. Add to your stylesheet `header * {background-color: transparent}` - it can be fixed your problem.

Comment: the problem persists even if i save it

Comment: @Muhammad5777 provide html

Comment: Ok, Now i have added the html and css

Comment: @Muhammad5777 I changed the answer above, take a look.

Comment: it is bad practice to refer to the tag in the code.
It is better to add a class to the element and refer to it (ex: <header class="header">)
Also, it is bad practice to give such properties as the background color through an asterisk, this will create a lot of problems in the future.

Comment: the asterisk was used to set a default background colour, the elements where the colour mattered the colour was given through the class. 
and the only use of the header element is to make a header so it is fine to refer to it as an element in css, referring to it through class does not solve the problem anyways.

Comment: @Muhammad5777 you can see [here](https://codepen.io/aglovlyuk/pen/oNMyPpb) my fixes

Comment: so, there is no way that you know of to resolve the problem without removing the asterist tag?

Comment: @Muhammad5777 and by the way, header can be used many times in markup: main header, header of article etc. You can look [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header#examples)

Comment: In your code your problem can be fixed like this: `header * {background-color: transparent}`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).